# StickersManager class not found for Quickblox

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, quickblox

I am trying to use Quickblox's sample chat application.

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

But I am getting this error "The import vc908 cannot be resolved"
At this line :

```
import vc908.stickerfactory.StickersManager;
```

I have used these libs : 
 - quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.2.6.jar
 - quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.2.6.jar

Also Added these :
- android-support-v7-appcompat
- google-play-services_lib
- pull-to-refresh

Answer (score 3):

StickersManager is a part of StickerPipe library. To use stickers functionality, you must include dependency to this library

```
       repositories {
           maven { url  'http://maven.stickerpipe.com/artifactory/stickerfactory' }
        }


       dependencies {
           compile('vc908.stickers:stickerfactory:0.2.2@aar') {
              transitive = true;
           }
       }
```

This integration described at [Stickers section](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Stickers) of documentation

You need use android studio to build project. If you use Eclipse, try to migrate with [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

**UPDATE**

Eclipse users now can follow [this instructions](https://github.com/908Inc/stickerpipe-android-sdk-for-eclipse) to add StickerPipe library

And [another sample](https://github.com/908Inc/stickerpipe-chat-sample) with StickerPipe library